# VueJs Sass-loader TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

Hello guys I have installed Sass-loader in my vueJs project but I get this error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/home/etali/Programmation/Web/VueJs/twotter-vueJs/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:25:24)
```

When I wanted to use scss in my components.

I'm using @vue/cli 4.5.13
the version of sass-loader is 12.1.0

thank you

Comment: common error - use `"sass-loader": "^10.2.0",` in your devDependencies - don't forget to npm install or yarn install after changing the package.json - also, for some reason I've put `"sass": "<1.33.0"` in my vue apps - I think that's to remove an annoying deprecation warning

Comment: thank you  I tried but nothing changed

Comment: worked for me, can you check to see what version sass-loader you now have

Comment: i have restart the server and it's working thank you

Comment: yes, that would be important :p

Answer (score 0):

`sass-loader` starting with v.11 [require webpack 5](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v11.0.0).
The best for now is just to use version ^10